# Does PHP know when a connection has been closed?

Tags: php, iis

Suppose a page takes a long time to generate, some large report for example, and the user closes the browser, or maybe they press refresh, does the PHP engine stop generating the page from the original request?

And if not, what can one do to cope with users refreshing a page a lot that causes an expensive report to be generated.

I have tried this and it seems that it does not stop any running query on the database. But that could be an engine problem, not PHP.

Extra info:
IIS7
MS SQL Server via ODBC

Answer (score 3):

When you send a request to the server, it is executed on the server without any communication with the browser until information is sent back to the browser. When PHP tries to send data back to the browser, it will fail and therefore the script will exit.

However, if you have a lot of code executing before any headers are sent, this will continue to execute until the headers are sent and a failed response is received.

Answer (score 2):

PHP knows when a connection has been closed when it tries to output some data (and fails). `echo`, `print`, `flush`, etc. Aside from this, no, it doesn't; everything else is happening on the server end.

Comment: Looking into this and testing with it. It doesn't seem that simple, because both PHP and IIS have their own buffers so that `flush` doesn't appear to guarantee that it will attempt to go back to the browser. Will carry on looking in to it. Please let me know if you have had this working and if you needed to change buffer sizes.

Answer (score 2):

There is little in the way of passing back information about the browser state once a request has been made (or in your case, in progress)

To know if a user is still connected to your site, you will need to implement a long poll / comet or perhaps a web socket.

Alternatively - you may want to run the long query initiated via an ajax call - while keeping the main browser respsonsive (not white screened). This allows you to detect if the browser is closed during the long query with a Javascript event onbeforeunload() to notify your backend that the user has left. (I'm not sure how you would interupt a query in progress from another HTTP request though)

Answer (score 1):

PHP have two functions to control this. **set_time_limit(num)** able to increase the limit before a page execution "dies". If you don't expand that limit, a page running "too long" will die. Bad for a long process.  Also you need **[ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)(TRUE)** so the server don't close the PHP process if the server detect that the page has ben closed in the client side.

You may also need to check for memory leaks if you are writing something that use much memory and run for several hours.

Answer (score 0):

When you send a request to the server the server will go away and perform the appropriate actions.  IIS/SQL Server does not know if the browser has been closed (and it is not IIS/SQL Server's responsibility to understand this) so it will execute the commands (as told to do so by the PHP engine until it has finished or until the engine kills any transactions).  Since your report could be dynamic, IIS will not cache page requests, SQL Server however can cache the last previously ran queries therefore you will see some performance gain from the database backend.